# Ubuntu 16.04/Postfix can't receive emails

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

We had our VPS already configured, but my co-worker accidently installed sendmail. Postfix went crazy and many errors popped out, postfix refused to run. I uninstalled sendmail, reconfigured/reinstalled postfix but now our server can send mails, but not receive.

Using roundcube as a client. Mails are not bounced back to sender for some reason, not sure what can I do? It looks like mails are coming but not shown anywhere, also I can not find them in/var/mail anywhere. Where are the logs located?

Thanks for any advice.

Here is the **main.cf** file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mpt.sk
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, mpt.sk, mail.mpt.sk, localhost.mpt.sk, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
```

**mail.log** when I try to send a mail:

```
Jan 17 10:32:03 mail postfix/smtpd[5798]: connect from unknown[103.207.38.154]
Jan 17 10:32:03 mail dovecot: auth: Warning: auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: Connection reset by peer
Jan 17 10:32:06 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mpt>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=5810, secured, session=<jf5OhfViwQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 17 10:32:06 mail dovecot: imap(mpt): Disconnected: Logged out in=376 out=3001
Jan 17 10:32:12 mail postfix/smtpd[5798]: warning: unknown[103.207.38.154]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jan 17 10:32:12 mail postfix/smtpd[5798]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[103.207.38.154]
Jan 17 10:32:12 mail postfix/smtpd[5798]: disconnect from unknown[103.207.38.154]
Jan 17 10:32:12 mail postfix/smtpd[5792]: connect from unknown[103.207.38.154]
```

**mail.err** has one old message:

```
Jan 17 09:47:34 mail dovecot: imap-login: Error: read(anvil) failed: EOF
```

mail.warn is not present anywhere.

Ouput of **ss -tnl**

```
root@mail:~# ss -tnl
State      Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      100                       *:110                      *:*
LISTEN     0      100                       *:143                      *:*
LISTEN     0      100                       *:465                      *:*
LISTEN     0      32                        *:21                       *:*
LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                       *:*
LISTEN     0      100                       *:25                       *:*
LISTEN     0      100                       *:993                      *:*
LISTEN     0      100                       *:995                      *:*
LISTEN     0      50                127.0.0.1:3306                     *:*
LISTEN     0      100                       *:587                      *:*
LISTEN     0      100                      :::110                     :::*
LISTEN     0      100                      :::143                     :::*
LISTEN     0      128                      :::80                      :::*
LISTEN     0      100                      :::465                     :::*
LISTEN     0      128                      :::22                      :::*
LISTEN     0      100                      :::25                      :::*
LISTEN     0      128                      :::443                     :::*
LISTEN     0      100                      :::993                     :::*
LISTEN     0      100                      :::995                     :::*
LISTEN     0      100                      :::587                     :::*
```

Comment: What does `/var/log/mail.log` and `/var/mail/mail.warn` and `/var/log/mail.err` say when you try to send an e-mail?

Comment: Please, show us output of: `ss -tnl`. Does your firewall allow access to the port 25?

Comment: Do you get any error message in the mail client? Is 103.207.38.154 the IP of the client?

Comment: Evgeniy, just updated the question. Vidarlo, you mean roundcube as mail client? I think "connect from unknown" will be me trying to send an email from my gmail account. Those messages just do not come back as undelivered, they seem to be delivered.

Comment: I've sent a test email to root on your server and it accept it. I think, your Dovecot auth config (SASL) is incorrect. Please, recheck your  `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf` (service auth {...}) [https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL]

Comment: Well this is what was in the tutorial:

# Postfix smtp-auth
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
mode = 0660
user = postfix
group = postfix
}

I am trying to receive an email to mail mpt@mpt.sk. Was thinking whether server "knows" to which email adress the mail need to be attached.

Comment: Check your mail, there should be my test message.

Comment: It is not there, not a sign of any mail.

Comment: You can manually send an email and check the logs after it:
https://pastebin.com/gvqWQS7F
`$ tail -20 /var/log/mail.log`

Comment: I tried sending an email with echo command, output:

https://pastebin.com/6JKhxkC7

Nothing special except for this "SASL LOGIN authentication failed".. I do not know, is there any way how to re-configure whole email system again? Without removing existing emails / database

Answer (score 1):

Not even sure what does that line do, but commenting out **mailbox_command** in file main.cf did the trick.

So basicly replace:

```
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

with:

```
# mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mail_command =
```

Note that it did not worked before I added the second line with blank variable.

Why it did not work? No one knows, this problem is solved for now but took me a hell of a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should replace this line:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

to that:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks
        reject_unauth_destination
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain
```

In your case `permit_sasl_authenticated` checked your AUTH param for a recipient, but should do it for a sender (you've done it in smtpd_relay_restrictions).

You also can add that if you want to filter bad senders:
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks
        reject_non_fqdn_sender
        reject_unknown_sender_domain

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it did not worked. Everything is the same, rebooted the device, but still no emails received. Thinking about re-configuring the whole machine.